# Mover un nodo de tipo elemento

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Por qué tengo que pulsar dos veces el botón para que me cambie de posición los elementos de la lista?

```js
function cambiarPosicion() {
  var lista1 = document.getElementById('lista');
  var hijo = lista1.firstChild;
  var lista2 = document.getElementById('lista2');
  lista2.appendChild(hijo);
}
```

```html
  <ul id="lista">
    <li>
      Primero
    </li>
    <li>
      Segundo
    </li>
    <li>
      Tercero
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="Cambiar posicion" onClick="cambiarPosicion()">
  <ul id="lista2">
  </ul>
```

Comment: Ahora que me doy cuenta el codigo html se ve directamente :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que tienes que usar es [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild):

```js
function cambiarPosicion() {
  var lista1 = document.getElementById('lista');
  var hijo = lista1.firstElementChild;
  var lista2 = document.getElementById('lista2');
  lista2.appendChild(hijo);
}
```

```html
  <ul id="lista">
    <li>
      Primero
    </li>
    <li>
      Segundo
    </li>
    <li>
      Tercero
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="Cambiar posicion" onClick="cambiarPosicion()">
  <ul id="lista2">
  </ul>
```

El problema con [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) es que también considera los espacios en blanco, observa la propiedad `"data"` cuando haces un `console.log(hijo)`:

```js
function cambiarPosicion() {
  var lista1 = document.getElementById('lista');
  var hijo = lista1.firstChild;
  console.log(hijo);
  var lista2 = document.getElementById('lista2');
  lista2.appendChild(hijo);
}
```

```html
  <ul id="lista">
    <li>
      Primero
    </li>
    <li>
      Segundo
    </li>
    <li>
      Tercero
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="Cambiar posicion" onClick="cambiarPosicion()">
  <ul id="lista2">
  </ul>
```

¿Lo viste? Es un salto de línea:

```
"data": "\n    ",
```

Esto pasa porque el espacio en blanco es considerado también como un nodo del elemento. Para que funcione con `firstChild` tendrías que tener todo el `<ul></ul>` en una misma línea:

```js
function cambiarPosicion() {
  var lista1 = document.getElementById('lista');
  var hijo = lista1.firstChild;
  var lista2 = document.getElementById('lista2');
  lista2.appendChild(hijo);
}
```

```html
  <ul id="lista"><li>Primero</li><li>Segundo</li><li>Tercero</li></ul>
  <input type="button" value="Cambiar posicion" onClick="cambiarPosicion()">
  <ul id="lista2">
  </ul>
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, gracias¡¡  Una duda mas, ¿Seria entonces mas correcto poner firstElementChild o  poner firstChild y en el documento de html no dejar espacios? (Queda mas ordenado con firstElementChild, porque si pongo todo junto en el documento html queda un pelin feo)

Comment: @Vendetta el orden siempre importa y, como tu mencionas, se ve feo todo en la misma línea. También es menos legible, es más fácil leer un código que está ordenado y que respeta los espacio y la indentación. Definitivamente tienes que usar `firstElementChild` a menos que tengas una buena razón para no hacerlo.

Answer (score 4):

En vez de usar la propiedad firstChild así:

```
lista1.firstChild
```

Usa esta otra:

```
lista1.firstElementChild
```

En tu HTML, los espacios en blanco que dejas para dar formato a la vista de tu HTML son considerados nodos texto. Por lo que cuando haces `lista1.firstChild`, te está devolviendo los nodos que son espacios, enter, tabulaciones, etc.

Por lo tanto, el primer click que haces, remueve un nodo texto que contiene el caracter de la tecla enter y otros espacios, y los agrega en el nodo *lista2*. El segundo click encuentra el nodo *li* dentro de *lista* y lo agrega dentro de *lista2*. El tercer click de nuevo nodo texto (*espacios*), y así...

Para comprobar eso, puedes dejar *firstChild* como está y cambiar tu HTML para que no tenga espacios:

```
<ul id="lista"><li>Primero</li><li>Segundo</li><li>Tercero</li></ul>
<input type="button" value="Cambiar posicion" onClick="cambiarPosicion()">
<ul id="lista2">
</ul>
```

Como sea, esto es horrible para todos, pero sirve para comprobar. 
Esto se encuentra documentado en inglés [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)

Comment: Entiendo que los espacios se consideren nodos de texto pero yo creía que era irrelevante poner los <li> juntos o separados en lo que es el documento.html. Para que me entiendas mejor lo que quiero decir:  si yo pusiera un texto y no le pusiera <br> , no habría salto de linea, por eso creía que era irrelevante el espacio entre los <li>          Igualmente muchas gracias, te voto el comentario (Y)   PD: Lo corregí y me sirvió

Comment: Es irrelevante para la vista. Esos caracteres de enter y tabulaciones se eliminan en la vista. Pero en el modelo (*DOM*) estos siguen formando parte del documento.